# Deleting files with Laravel Facade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a file using the Storage Facade but can't get it to work:

```
$filePath = 'app/data-export/';
$excelFile = storage_path($filePath . 'ExcelData.xlsx');
$deleted = Storage::disk('local')->delete($excelFile);
```

The file is there on the disk:

[image: screenshot of file hierarchy]

When I run the code, no errors are thrown and $deleted comes back true, but the file is not removed.

I've also tried

```
$deleted = Storage::delete($excelFile);
```

but that doesn't work either.

My filesystems.php is

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
        'throw'  => false,
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url'        => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw'      => false,
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver'                  => 's3',
        'key'                     => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret'                  => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region'                  => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket'                  => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url'                     => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint'                => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        'throw'                   => false,
    ],

],
```

PHP 8.2.0, Laravel 9.52.10, Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Since you wrote a comment it worked, but later deleted it. It is common to accept the answer if it helped, since it will help others looking at this post understanding what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the `Storage` facade, is it knows it own path. You do not have to provide the full path, instead this solution should suffice.

```
$excelFile = 'data-export/' . 'ExcelData.xlsx';
$deleted = Storage::disk('local')->delete($excelFile);
```

Comment: Thanks mrhn. That worked fine. Not sure how my previous comment got deleted. It wasn't intentional! I've now marked the answer as accepted.